# python / inaccurate speed in mouse movement / missing key presses during playback in python macro script

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros

```
import keyboard
import time
import mouse
import win32api
import os

recorded_actions = []


def checkMouseState(key):
    val = win32api.GetKeyState(key)
    #btnType = ['left', 'right']
    return 'down' if val < 0 else ''

def record_mouse_action(event):
    timestamp = time.time()
    recorded_actions.append((timestamp, event))

# Record keyboard actions with timestamps
def record_keyboard_action(event):
    timestamp = time.time()
    recorded_actions.append((timestamp, event))

m_button_state = checkMouseState(0x24)
macroStart = False

while not macroStart:
    new_m_button_state = checkMouseState(0x24)
    if new_m_button_state != m_button_state:
        m_button_state = new_m_button_state
        if new_m_button_state == '':
            print('Macro Recording ...')
            macroStart = True

mouse.hook(record_mouse_action)
keyboard.hook(record_keyboard_action)


until = False
while not until:
    new_m_button_state = checkMouseState(0x24)
    if new_m_button_state != m_button_state:
        m_button_state = new_m_button_state
        if new_m_button_state == '':
            print('Macro Recording End')
            until = True


mouse.unhook(record_mouse_action)
keyboard.unhook(record_keyboard_action)

last_time = None
for action in recorded_actions:
    timestamp, event = action

    if last_time is not None:
        time.sleep(event.time - last_time)

    last_time = event.time



    # Perform the action (mouse or keyboard)
    if isinstance(event, mouse.ButtonEvent):
        mouse.press(event.button) if event.event_type == 'down' else mouse.release(event.button)
    elif isinstance(event, mouse.MoveEvent):
        mouse.move(event.x, event.y)
    elif isinstance(event, mouse.WheelEvent):
        mouse.wheel(event.delta)
    elif isinstance(event, keyboard.KeyboardEvent):
        keyboard.press(event.name) if event.event_type == 'down' else keyboard.release(event.name)


print ("exit")
```

im making a mouse keyboard macro script for python.
if you press 'home key', record starts and it plays the playback when its pressed again.
the problems i have are

1. When playing the recorded, the speed of mouse movement isn't as same as the recorded.
   the cursor moves smooth but not the same as recorded.
2. It misses pressing some keys during playback especially when using capital letters. I believe its related to pressing shift.
   for example, if I type "The Home" and play it, sometimes it would type like "Te Home" or "The Hme" missing keys after capital letters.

i tried other mouse and keyboard modules such as pynput, but it doesnt seem to record the full movement of mouse.. also tried chatgpt hoping it could fix my problem but it didnt.